# How do I pass Java command line options to Coursier when the Java option is two words?

Tags: coursier

I need to pass the command line option, --add-exports, to java.  Example:

--add-exports java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED

If I try to use the --java-opt for Coursier, it does not work and I get an error.  It appears Coursier is not parsing the two word argument needed for --add-exports.

```
cs launch --java-opt --add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED com.google.googlejavaformat:google-java-format:1.13.0 -- src/main/java/com/example/demo/DemoApplication.java
```

The error for the above example is

```
Cannot find app jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED in channels io.get-coursier:apps
```

What is the correct command line syntax for Couriser to pass the Java '--add-exports' option?

**Found solution** by using the Coursier -J syntax as documented [here](https://get-coursier.io/docs/2.0.0-RC6-10/cli-launch#java-options).

-J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED

Comment: Have you tried `cs launch --java-opt "--add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED com.google.googlejavaformat:google-java-format:1.13.0" ...`?

Comment: @Progman No luck with the quotes like that either.  I get an error saying the option is unrecognized.  I'm using openjdk 16.0.1 2021-04-20.  ❯ cs launch --java-opt "--add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED" com.google.googlejavaformat:google-java-format:1.13.0 -- src/main/java/com/example/demo/DemoApplication.java

JVMJ9VM007E Command-line option unrecognised: --add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.